Outdoor Electrical Box With Broken Screws
I removed a broken GFCI, got the new one wired up, and when I went to put it back in the box, I saw why it had been secured to the box with only one screw.  One side already had screw sheared off in the hole and when I unscrewed the one securing the receptacle to the box, I sheared that screw off.
The box was designed to enclose the entire screw as it went in, so it's not like I can just access the broken piece from the back.  It's likely from the 1980s because it's mounted into the stone of a small addition that was added to the house around 1986.
With nothing to mount to, I removed the receptacle, put screw nuts on the wires, tapes the nuts to the wires, and then used gorilla tape over the box for now.  I doubt that will hold.
Other than cutting into the mortar, removing the old box, and replacing it/mortaring the new box in place, do I have any options?  As I have zero experience with that solution, I'm hoping there's an easier one.


Replacing the box is the best/probably only code allow option.  I would be surprised(does not take much) if the mortar is what is holding the box in the wall, more of covering a gap/looking nice.

you tube just threw this my way: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/mKPnJRqbsXQ

You could repair that with some two part  metal epoxy, then tap a new hole for the screw.
Or you could drill where the screw hole used to be all the way through the back of the box. Then very carefully, as you don't know what's behind it. But if it's anything solid use a longer construction screw for that side of the device into the backing.
Or, probably easiest, instead of a screw use a nut and bolt.  You seem to have access to place a nut behind the hole through the unused side entry port.  Use a springy lock washer to prevent it from turning as you tighten the bolt from the front.  Or embed the nut into a small piece of PVC conduit using heat, that will hold it in place.  Or a short bolt from behind, through that port, then a coupling nut that you can tighten before installing the device, and the device would be installed with a regular bolt into the coupling nut.
Either way, Make sure the device and the box are connected positively by a ground wire screwed to a terminal in the box.  Right or wrong, It may have relied on a ground path through that screw which will no longer exist with either of these repairs.

As I’m reading more, I wonder if I could use a small hacksaw to cut away the old screw mount, fill it with J-B Weld (just learning about this product), and then use a tap set to thread new holes. Haven’t used a tap set and don’t know what size I’d need, but assume I can dig that up.  I’m not sure what’s to the side or behind the box.  Has romex wiring, thankfully.  Most of the house is old 2-wire with cloth sheathing.

@scholl43  Most epoxies(J-B) want a very clean surface to bond to.  I think a small rotary tool with a grinding wheel will fit better than a hacksaw.  You know you just needed any reason to buy one.

You don't need to cut it away. Just clean the whole area with water (because it's so grimy) then Goof-Off or WD40 then soap or detergent.  Then apply the JB Weld in a great gob over where the old hole was.  You can use the corner of a box supported on a piece of wood to keep it from dripping away initially.  It's hard to shape precisely so don't try.  It's easy to sand later, and you don't need it to be any particular shape.  Just over-apply, then saw or sand away anything that interferes with anything.  Use a punch through the socket mounting hole to mark where to drill.    ..... [1/2]

[ 2/2 ]    Practice with the JB Weld on any random hunk of wood or plastic to get the feel of how it goes on, dries, and sands.   And practice with the tap first in scrap plastic or metal and  then in a practice gob of JB Weld.

I think the coupling nut would be my first choice.  It's basically like the epoxy except you don't have to make it.  Just grind a flat face on the broken part with a Dremel, drill into the socket and mount it.  5 minutes total.   With the epoxy it's several days of practicing, waiting for it to dry, shaping, swearing, etc.

I’m at the disadvantage of being 800 miles from my dremel, drill/driver, and other tools, unfortunately, so I was looking at the cut/J-B Weld as a solution that might work with the least additional investments (I also have one day to do this before leaving).  I’ve used Bondo before, so I have some experience with 2 part epoxies that might not want to stay where I want them due to gravity.  Not  sure how well that translates to J-B Weld, but probably better than nothing.

Goop is goop. You'll be fine.  You don't even need a tap.  Put oil on the box screw and embed it in the epoxy then unscrew it when it's set.

I would think it easier to simply use the actual (machine) screw that will be used.  Coat it in oil, then hold it in place, slather the epoxy/JBW around the broken tapped post.  When set, gently unscrew.  But I think an even easier idea would be to get a couple of nuts for the machine screw, put them on the end of the screw, and glue the nuts in place.

if gluing use a connector (long) nut or ideally a  threaded insert

Cut/grind off the corroded boss to remove the rusting screw stub and drill through into the unused the conduit opening and install a clip-on speed nut there. (or a Rivnut if you are posh - but there might not be enough meat for a Rivnut)
clean the sealing surface of the box and ensure that the replaced outlet seals against it.

these things:   https://www.youtube.com/shorts/mKPnJRqbsXQ

But only if they make them in size:"American"
I guess you could could DIY with a strip of stainless banding and a rivnut or a clip-on speed nut.

The inside of the box is oxidized so it does not serve its purpose - sealing the unprotected wiring inside.
I'm quite sure the moisture inside the box was the reason for the GFCI failure. Patching it around and keeping the sealing not working asks for yet another GFCI to break...
Get the damaged box out, install new one and seal it well, both from outside and inside.You really don't want to have water / moisture inside that box.

You probably want to leave a drain hole in the bottom of the box...

I'd go for water absorbent instead. Or be sure the water won't get in though the drain.

That's not the screw that's broken, it's the box. And since that's probably an indeterminate alloy ("pot metal") it's not repairable.
Replace the box, using new glands etc.
